# Checking if a list is inside another list (regardless of order) in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to build a slot machine game where you get 10 coins for getting 3 cherries (in **any** order) and I have an if statement like this:

```
#slotresult has the format ['x','x','x','x']
threecherries= ["cherry","cherry","cherry"]
  if set(threecherries).issubset(slotresult):
    print("Nice! You have won 10 coins!")
```

The problem is that it says 'You have won 10 coins!' when only one or more cherries appears in the slotresult, but I want it to only say this when there are three cherries there in **any** order.

I've also tried alternatives but they won't match if the result is like:
`['cherry','lemon','cherry','cherry]` as the 'cherries' aren't all next to each other!

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Converting into set removes duplicates, so just compare the lists

Answer (score 3):

You can use `list.count`.

```py
if slotresult.count('cherry') == 3:
    print("Nice! You have won 10 coins!")
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to oversimplify things!

Comment: @ZacB Happy to help.